# How to adjust number of decimal places in the default values shown in an input matrix and used in subsequent calculations, without using rounding?

Tags: html, r, shiny

The below example code has 3 user input matrixes: the first, `base_input`, allows the user to make static inputs and the next 2 user input matrixes, `var_1_input` and `var_2_input`, are fed the values from `base_input` and allow the user to alter the time dimension in their respective left-most user input columns labeled "X". How can I make the default values show 2 decimal places in the right-most user input columns, while not disturbing the current feature whereby if the user enters values with > 2 decimal places, those longer decimals are retained? As shown in the image below. I'm only interested in the decimals for the right-most user input columns because the time periods (columns X, the left-most columns of `var_1_input` and `var_2_input`) represent indivisible whole months.

I fiddled with `sprintf()` but that doesn't work because numeric values need to flow through the matrixes to undergo calculations (those calculations not shown in this reduced code). My guess is there is an html solution, but I am very unfamiliar with html.

[image]

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(rep(20,2),2, 1,dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputVary <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max =10, value = 5),
  h5(strong("Variable (Y) over window (W):")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vectors")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    varNames <- c("A", "B")
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      list(
        h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[i], "(Y) at time X:"))),
        matInputVary(paste0("var_", i, "_input"), input$periods, input$base_input[i, 1])
      )
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Expanding on accepted solution:**

Below I expand on Stéphane Laurent's `js` solution a bit in order to retain the complete values entered by the user when the values have > 2 decimal places. Basically, when formatting each cell (`shiny:bound` event), it checks the number of decimal places in the cell's text. If it's < 2, it formats the number to show 2 decimal places and if it's more, it retains the existing decimal places.

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:bound', function(event) {
  var $elem = $(event.target);
  if($elem.hasClass('vue-input')) {
    $elem.find('td').each(function() { 
      var $td = $(this);
      var columnIndex = $td.index();
      var $table = $td.closest('.vue-input');
      var tableId = $table.attr('id');
      var isVarInput = tableId.startsWith('var_') && tableId.endsWith('_input');
      var text = $td.find('span').text();
      var num = parseFloat(text);
      
      if (!isNaN(num)) {
        if (isVarInput && columnIndex == 0) {
          // Format with 0 decimal places for the first column of var_x_input
          $td.find('span').html(num.toFixed(0));
        } else {
          // Use 2 decimal places for the second column of var_x_input and other cases
          var decimalPlaces = (text.split('.')[1] || []).length;
          var fixed = decimalPlaces < 2 ? 2 : decimalPlaces;
          $td.find('span').html(num.toFixed(fixed));
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('focusout', '.vue-input table td input', function(e) {
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    var columnIndex = $td.index();
    var $table = $td.closest('.vue-input');
    var tableId = $table.attr('id');
    var isVarInput = tableId.startsWith('var_') && tableId.endsWith('_input');
    
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if ($td.children().is('span')) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        var $span = $td.find('span');
        var text = $span.text();
        var num = parseFloat(text);
        
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
          if (isVarInput && columnIndex == 0) {
            // Format with 0 decimal places for the first column of var_x_input
            $span.html(num.toFixed(0));
          } else {
            // Use 2 decimal places for the second column of var_x_input and other cases
            var decimalPlaces = (text.split('.')[1] || []).length;
            var fixed = decimalPlaces < 2 ? 2 : decimalPlaces;
            $span.html(num.toFixed(fixed));
          }
        }
      }
    }, 50);
  });
});
"
```

Comment: Does `sprintf('%.2f', input$base_input[i, 1])` help? (see `?sprintf` for a multitude of options)

Comment: It works to an extent but does not persistently show 2 decimals. The solution below by Stéphane Laurent does work and I revised my question to take his code slightly further so numbers entered with >2 decimal places are completely retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

js <- "
// this code will format the cells when the matrices inputs appear
$(document).on('shiny:bound', function(event) {
  var $elem = $(event.target);
  if($elem.hasClass('vue-input')) {
    $elem.find('td span').each(function() { 
      var num = parseFloat($(this).text());
      if(!isNaN(num)) {
        $(this).html(num.toFixed(2));
      }
    });
  }
});
// this code will format the numbers in the edited cells
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('focusout', '.vue-input table td input', function(e) {
    var $td = $(this).parent();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if($td.children().is('span')) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        var $span = $td.find('span');
        $span.html(parseFloat($span.text()).toFixed(2));
      }
    });
  });
});
"

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(rep(20,2),2, 1,dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputVary <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max =10, value = 5),
  h5(strong("Variable (Y) over window (W):")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vectors")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    varNames <- c("A", "B")
    lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      list(
        h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[i], "(Y) at time X:"))),
        matInputVary(paste0("var_", i, "_input"), input$periods, input$base_input[i, 1])
      )
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```